# android softkeyboard key not hitting properly

Tags: android, android-xml, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I'm modifying the sample softkeyboard app from the android sdk. I noticed that the alphabet keys seem to get hit even if I touch at position below the key. More specifically, if I touch near the top boundary of the "A" key, then the keyboard actually registers "Q" instead. It seems the bounding rectangle for each key extends to the empty space below it and sometimes even owning some top portion of the key below.

In addition, I tried modifying the layout of the bottom row so that the space key is larger as below. However, as soon as I do this, there is a portion to the right of the space key that does not register when I touch. This region seems to occupy 10% of the width. Any ideas how I can debug these issues?

```
  <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="123" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyWidth="55%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="." android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="10" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_return" 
                android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
```

Comment: You may want to look into the vertical correction setting in android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView or even the AOSP keyboard code which can also be interesting to look at.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. Any suggestions on the spacebar issues?

Comment: I'd probably research those key edge flags.  The AOSP version has some interesting logic there, I didn't really look at what the SDK class has in comparison, but the settings in your XML make it seem like it must be doing something.

Comment: thanks, after debugging the sdk for a while I came to notice the getNearestKeys method. A quick search brought up the duplicate SO post  as mentioned in my answer below.

Comment: As for the vertical correction, @ChrisStratton is correct. I looked into it and all I had to do was add android:verticalCorrection="0dp" to res\layout\input.xml and keys started working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer for the space key portion of the above:
[android custom keyboard: touch area of space key not completely covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350628/android-custom-keyboard-touch-area-of-space-key-not-completely-covered)

As for the vertical correction, @ChrisStratton is correct. I looked into it and all I had to do was add `android:verticalCorrection="0dp"` to `res\layout\input.xml` and keys started hitting correctly.