# custom keyboard space bar with more than android:keyWidth="40%p" not clickable

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-keyboard

i am developing a keyboard but when i put  android:keyWidth="40%p" more than 40.  right side of the space key is not clickble.

i use android studio. and custom keyboardview with xml like this

full code is

```
 <Keyboard ><Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key  android:keyWidth="10%" android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="43"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:keyWidth="10%" android:codes="-6" android:keyLabel="f"   />
    <Key android:keyWidth="10%p"    android:codes="44" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyLabel=","/>
    <Key android:keyWidth="45%p" android:codes="32" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyLabel="space"/>
    <Key android:keyWidth="10%p" android:codes="46" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyLabel="." />
    <Key android:keyWidth="13%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"   android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="enter"    />
</Row>
```

this outputs but android:keyWidth="45%p"  only 40% of space bar is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to a method from Keyboard#**getNearestKeys** that doesn't return proper values for wide buttons. You can solve the problem by extending the Keyboard class and overriding the getNearestKeys method.

like this

```
  public class CustomKeyboard extends Keyboard {

    public CustomKeyboard(Context context, int xmlLayoutResId) {
        super(context, xmlLayoutResId);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getNearestKeys(int x, int y) {
        List<Key> keys = getKeys();
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            if (keys.get(i).isInside(x, y)) return new int[]{i};
        }
        return new int[0];
    } }
```

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350628/android-custom-keyboard-touch-area-of-space-key-not-completely-covered)